# Regex to allow just letters and special characters

Tags: regex

I'm currently using the following regex to allow only characters:

```
"^[a-zA-Z]+$"
```

I would like to change it so that it allows characters and special characters like '-', and other characters which are found in non-English characters.

How can I do it?

Comment: Sounds kinda like you want to allow all characters.. which would just be `"^.+$"`. Perhaps it would be easier to say which characters you don't want to allow?

Comment: Hey Ivan! What kind of regex are you looking into using (Perl, posix, ...?!?) and would you have an explicit list of characters that need to be matched (or, as Pudge just said, of characters you DON'T want to match)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to allow specific special characters, simply include them in the character class:

```
"^[a-zA-Z\-]+$"
```

Some special characters need to be escaped, some don't.

But if you want to accept every character except numeric characters, it might be simpler to simply use:

```
"^\D+$"
```

Comment: "it might be simpler to simply..." doesn't sound as simple as it should be... oops!

Answer (score 0):

hmm try this regex: "\D" it allows only characters and no signs. Its equivalent to [^\d].
you can add special characters just by writing them to it. For example: "[\D-+#$]+$"